# Update Hash to HMAC-SHA-512

Tags: opencart, payment-gateway, opencart2.x, sha512

I am trying to use a payment module in OpenCart version 2.0.1.1, and I need to update our Hash to HMAC-SHA-512, so the checkout page authorizes successfully. 
I just don´t know how to change the hash and where exactly I can do this.

We use Plesk, with PHP 7. The domain is www.didikong.de

The payment module is WireCard Checkout Page version 1.2.0.

So this wirecard generates a Fingerprint, which is encrypted via HMAC-SHA-512. And our website uses SSL.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am really not sure if the version 1.5.2 of opencart-wcp was still compatible with 2.0.1.1 but I would try that first. There was a client library update between 1.2.0 and 1.5.2 in which the algorythm was updated. If you don't have a test system where you could try it out just check the changes in the client lib. More in particular look into the `/system/library/wirecard/vendor/wirecard/checkout-client-library/library/WirecardCEE/QPay/FrontendClient.php` file and see if the setHashAlgorithm is using the `WirecardCEE_Stdlib_Fingerprint::HASH_ALGORITHM_HMAC_SHA512` constant. If not, just change it to the mentioned constant and you should be good to go. If you get any errors regarding some missing things consider updating the `/system/library/wirecard/vendor/wirecard/checkout-client-library/library/WirecardCEE/Stdlib/Client/ClientAbstract.php` to the newest version.